# how to do jquery once fade out has finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to fade out a div on a click but also change some css values.

the issue im having is that the values change while the fade out is happening (too early). I need the values to change once the fade out has finished:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#r_text').click(function() { 
    $(".box1_d").fadeOut();
    $(".box1_c").css("top","0px");
});
</script>
```

Now when i run that, everything works but just not exactly how i'd like it.. I need the css values to be changed once the fadeout has finished, not while it's still happening.

is this possible?

if so, any ideas how?

thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a callback function to modify the `.css()` as the second parameter to `fadeOut()`.  It will fire when the fade completes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var fadeTime = 500;
$('#r_text').click(function() { 
    $(".box1_d").fadeOut(fadeTime, function() {
      $(".box1_c").css("top","0px");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided you use jQuery version >= 1.5, you can/should [utilize the Deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) instead of using the callback parameter:

```
$('#r_text').click((function () {
    var animations = {
        initial: function () {
            return $(".box1_d").fadeOut(1500);
        },
        following: function () {
            return $(".box1_c").css("top","0px").animate({fontSize: '150%'});
        },
        onDone: function () { 
            alert('DONE!'); 
        }
    };
    return function(e) {
        $.when(animations.initial())
            .pipe(animations.following)
            .done(animations.onDone);
        e.preventDefault();
    };
}()));
```

JsFiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/wGcgS/2/